How Islamist is the HTS governance model, compared to the Taliban?
Although HTS has de facto ruled over Idlib for years, there's not a lot of info in English about their governance. I did find out that they ran some nasty prisons and even disappeared some of their opponents (like ISIS) without some kind of formal process. In this they somewhat resemble the Taliban. But what about other issues, like women's education, mandatory veil, etc.?
Mkay, the HTS did seem to introduce segregated education last year.
One interesting point I've discovered is that HTS' 2nd in hierarchy gave a 2021 lecture apparently praising the Taliban. But not much is said about its actual contents. And he apparently made a point to deliver that lecture "in a modern outfit", something that I'm not entirely sure the Taliban would have appreciated.

Abbreviations like HTS should be spelled out once at the first use in the question body. A link to further information would also be nice.

My understanding is that the US is in a process of a pivot from labeling them as terrorist, to declaring them good guys, resisting Assad's dictatorship and Iranian meddling in Levant. So it is reasonable to expect that with every day we will learn more good things about them... at least as far as the "mainstream media" are concerned :D

@Wagthemainstreammediadog - According to the New York Times, they are "still deeply conservative, intolerant and authoritarian" and have not "moderated" their "hardline interpretation of Islam," so not everyone seems to want to let bygones be bygones. Though the Washington Post does say that the group has "distanced itself from its extremist roots." But some credit has to be given to the group itself: even a year ago, at least, it was trying to put on a more palatable face.

@Obie2.0 the strongest US ally in the region is Saudi Arabia - professing hardline interprétation of islam par excellence... so was bin Laden, when he was fighting Soviets, etc., etc.

@Wagthemainstreammediadog - Sure, but those are not precisely good things about them.

@Obie2.0 just good enough to be allies. I agree that it is not the same level of idealizing as we see in respect to Ukraine... but standards set by Ukraine and Russia are very different, and much closer to western.

(Note the French translation of HTS goes as Organization for the Liberation of the Levant, where Levant is a geographic designation of the "general region/Syria/Lebanon" ).
TLDR:
It seems to be a mixed bag and varies by chronology, with older events looking worse.  Maybe al-Jawlani's improved and become more pragmatic, maybe it was all tactical pretense.  Probably best to hold both possibilities in mind until the situation evolves a bit.  Especially if the rebel factions start seriously fighting in the future, with Assad gone.  (Reality check:  no stable, locals-supported, locals-chosen, government is going to be singing Kumbaya and preaching peace and tolerance to all and sundry minorities as per Western wishes).

2023 CSIS

HTS’s ideology has changed dramatically since Jolani’s days leading an al Qaeda affiliate. HTS’s current political-religious ideology frames the group as strictly Syria-focused and religiously moderate. Since 2017, HTS has incorporated various independent religious and political leaders into its internal institutions to appease factions and build a religious bureaucracy, a process that has helped moderate the group, at least on the surface. While HTS presents itself as less ideologically extreme than al Qaeda or ISIS, the brutal measures HTS uses to maintain control over its territory are a far cry from the benevolent, citizen-led government shown on its media outlets. Today, HTS is more recognizable as an authoritarian statelet than the transnational Islamist militia it once was.

2023 - Here's another bit from omrandstudies.org - Maintaining Mass Obedience: HTS’s Response to the Protests in Idlib, pre-offensive *
The issue the article refers to has more to do with stripping local councils of autonomy than Islamist practices per se.  The response would not pass muster in the West **, but isn't really that unusual for the regions' Western-backed regimes like Egypt.  And seems to fall short of Taliban, let alone ISIS, level of nastiness.
So, the response was both to coerce and to somewhat reform.

The protests posed a new challenge to HTS, threatening both its governance model and the narrative it uses to portray itself as not only a better alternative to the regime, but also to its rival opposition’s Syrian Interim Government - a narrative that was employed to legitimize its attempts to expand influence into areas controlled by the Syrian National Army. As protesters demanded the overthrow of al-Jawlani’s rule (9), the latter calibrated his response by employing a mix of persuasion and coercion tactics, such as using limited violence, announcing reforms, and launching mediation initiatives led by local governance bodies. These actions were aimed at containing the protests and restoring mass obedience in HTS-controlled areas.


By employing limited violence, such as deploying security or military forces, limited shootings, beating with sticks, and arresting activists and protesters, HTS aimed to maintain its strong image and project power without causing severe losses that could backfire and fuel further resentment. This calibrated violence was utilized to pressure localities into recognizing the reforms announced by the SSG and conceding to local settlements brokered by the local governance bodies.

So, this would be consistent with HTS - in 2023 - being worthy of criticism by the UN, but still short of some of the whackier Islamist movements of the past, including those from which HTS
2022 Here's an article in French I mentioned in comments, talking about Christian celebrations.

On July 19, Muhammad al Jawlani, leader of the Hayat Tahrir al Sham militia - "Organization for the Liberation of the Levant", a jihadist formation known in the past as Jabhat al Nusra - met with representatives of Christian communities still present in the villages of Qunaya, Yacoubia and al-Jadida, and announced its intention to "protect" their liturgical celebrations, also guaranteeing the progressive restitution of real estate seized in recent years to Christian owners. The militiamen of Tharir el Sham - report local sources - set up roadblocks near the village during the celebration, in order to ensure the peaceful conduct of the liturgy.

2021 This January 2021 (French) blog on the other hand speaks of dire abuse

In addition, the group screens all recruitment, administrative, educational and the judicial system. Its members systematically arrest those who demonstrate any form of opposition, many are tortured. Last year, a United Nations investigative report confirmed that HTS had detained, tortured and murdered numerous civilians who expressed "dissenting views", including journalists; Women and girls are “systematically discriminated against” and deprived of their freedom. In November, the UN reiterated its allegations and highlighted that HTS was responsible, among other things, for the execution of innocent women accused of adultery or blasphemy: HTS holds many who have been kidnapped and tortured in at least 32 prisons in Idlib; there is also talk of rape and murder.

2020 And this seems to be the source, in November 2020:

Spokesperson for the UN High Commissioner for Human Rights: Ravina Shamdasani
Location: Geneva **
Date: 20 November 2020


We have been receiving disturbing reports of continued detention of civilians, including humanitarian workers, in Idlib, northwestern Syria, in areas under the control of Hay'at Tahrir al-Sham (HTS) and other armed groups. We have also been receiving deeply troubling reports of executions following the detentions and so-called trials by the de facto authorities.


We have verified reports that several individuals were executed, for perceived affiliation with an opposing party, including Kurdish armed groups or the Syrian Government, or on allegations of blasphemy, adultery, theft or murder. International humanitarian law explicitly prohibits sentencing and executions without a previous judgment affording all necessary judicial guarantees. Under international law, executions carried out in violation of this prohibition may amount to a war crime

* do hope they know what they are talking about, but so far seem fairly solid and balanced.
** Well, mostly it wouldn't pass muster in the West.  Let's not forget waterboarding, extraordinary renditions and the like.  And also that the West's dealings with ex-ISIS personnel and hangers on has mostly been to leave them to rot in SDF camps in Syria.  Actual ISIS militants - not those in the above mentioned protests - are hard to deal with at scale within a rule of law system outside of wartime martial law.
